# How to pivot_longer with multiple column categories (none numeric) in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df similar to the following:

```
df <- data.frame("name" = c("sue","joe","tom"),
                 "x0_date" = c("2020-1-20", "2020-2-20", "2020-3-20"),
                 "x0_class" = c("biology", "physics", "chemistry"),
                 "x1_date" = c("2021-4-18", NA, "2021-6-18"),
                 "x1_class" = c("english", NA, "drama"))
df
  name   x0_date  x0_class   x1_date x1_class
1  sue 2020-1-20   biology 2021-4-18  english
2  joe 2020-2-20   physics      <NA>     <NA>
3  tom 2020-3-20 chemistry 2021-6-18    drama
```

I am trying to pivot longer such that my outcome is as follows:

```
  name      date     class
1  sue 2020-1-20   biology
2  sue 2021-4-18   english
3  joe 2020-2-20   physics
4  tom 2020-3-20 chemistry
5  tom 2021-6-18     drama
```

I guess I've only ever pivoted when some of the data is numeric, so I'm having trouble. I've tried something like:

```
test <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(matches("date|class"),
    names_to = c("date", "class"), 
    names_pattern = "(\\d+)_(.+)",
    values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

But the output isn't quite right. If it's relevant, my wide data is extremely wide ("x0" to "x_400"). Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need `names_to` as `.value`.  According to `?pivot_longer`

> names_to - If length >1, multiple columns will be created. In this case, one of names_sep or names_pattern must be supplied to specify how the column names should be split. There are also two additional character values you can take advantage of:

> NA will discard the corresponding component of the column name.

> ".value" indicates that the corresponding component of the column name defines the name of the output column containing the cell values, overriding values_to entirely.

Thus, specify that as `.value` and use `names_pattern` to capture only the characters that succeeds the `_` i.e. (`_(.*)`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = c(".value"),
       names_pattern = ".*_(.*)", values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  name  date      class    
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>    
1 sue   2020-1-20 biology  
2 sue   2021-4-18 english  
3 joe   2020-2-20 physics  
4 tom   2020-3-20 chemistry
5 tom   2021-6-18 drama
```

---

If we need the `x0`, `x1` prefix as another column, then we need to specify the column name for the prefix and also to capture the prefix part

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = c("categ", ".value"),
     names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  name  categ date      class    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>    
1 sue   x0    2020-1-20 biology  
2 sue   x1    2021-4-18 english  
3 joe   x0    2020-2-20 physics  
4 tom   x0    2020-3-20 chemistry
5 tom   x1    2021-6-18 drama
```

---

The reason the OP's code didn't work

```
df %>% 
+   pivot_longer(matches("date|class"),
+     names_to = c("date", "class"), 
+     names_pattern = "(\\d+)_(.+)",
+     values_drop_na = TRUE)
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   name  date  class value    
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    
 1 sue   0     date  2020-1-20
 2 sue   0     class biology  
 3 sue   1     date  2021-4-18
 4 sue   1     class english  
 5 joe   0     date  2020-2-20
 6 joe   0     class physics  
 7 tom   0     date  2020-3-20
 8 tom   0     class chemistry
 9 tom   1     date  2021-6-18
10 tom   1     class drama
```

is because it is capturing one or more digits (`\\d+`) before the `_` and then the rest (`.+`) as the column prefix, suffix, thus we get the 0, 1, from 'x0', 'x1' in 'date', the suffix part in 'class' and as we didn't specify the `.value`, the default column `value` will return with the values of the columns

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer, it was helpful to understand where my code went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

- We can use `Base R` `rbind` function by splitting `df` to list of `data.frame`s with column names `name , data , class`

```
lapply(1:((ncol(df)-1)/2) , \(i) df[c(1,2*i,2*i+1)]) |> 
lapply(\(x) {colnames(x) <- c("name" , "data" , "class") ; x}) |> 
do.call(rbind , args = _) |> na.omit()
```

- Output

```
  name      data     class
1  sue 2020-1-20   biology
2  joe 2020-2-20   physics
3  tom 2020-3-20 chemistry
4  sue 2021-4-18   english
6  tom 2021-6-18     drama
```